# getting original 3d cube back ...c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

Given a cube of N*N*N* dimensions. This cube is having some number on each of its vertex. Now this original cube is distorted such that number on any vertex at(i,j,k) is replaced by sum of all numbers in cuboid formed by (0,0,0) and (i,j,k) ..Now after distortion ..we have to get back the original cube ..
Suppose original cube is A then for every element in B(i,j,k)(the distorted on) we have used this following code ..

```
for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
   for(int j=n-1;j>=0;j--)
     for(int k=n-1;k>=0;k--)
     {
        for(c=0;c<=i;c++)
          for(c1=0;c1<=j;c1++)
             for(c2=0;c2<=k;c2++)
              B(i,j,k)=B(i,j,k)+A(c,c1,c2);
     }
```

what can be an efficient approach to get the original cube back ...I thought of storing the negative value of each vertex in B in any other cube (say C)  and then used same approach as above to get the original one ...though it din't work fine ...following was the approach which i tried..

```
C[50][50][50] // this C is already having values same as in B but with opposite sign
for(c=0;c<=i;c++)
 for(c1=0;c1<=j;c1++)
    for(c2=0;c2<=k;c2++)
       C(i,j,k)=C(i,j,k)+B(c,c1,c2);
```

P.S maximum size of cube is 50*50*50..any help plz..

Comment: I'm not following with the distortion. Since, `i`, `j` & `k` are constants it seems like you distort `B` (instead of A?) to the **same** cell in B - B(i,j,k). Should the distortion line look like this: `A(c,c1,c2) = A(c,c1,c2) + B(c,c1,c2)`?

Comment: maybe it’s `for (i = 0; i < c; i++)` … ?

Comment: look A is our original cube ..and that code is run for all i,j,k [0-n-1] ...that is ... 6 loops are used actually ...hope u got my point..

Comment: @unknown__ well… no because your code says otherwise

Comment: @unknown__ No. I'm trying to understand the distortion. The distortion code as it is written now - changes **only** the `B` cube and **only** one cell in it - `B(i,j,k)`.

Comment: the code as it is doesn’t make any sense. Please take a good look over it. If you will not fix it, or provide comprehensive explanation, I’ll vote to close as unclear.

Comment: code updated ..hope it is clear now ..:D

Comment: now that’s something completely different :))

Comment: just an intuition, but I don’t think it's possible to restore the original information. Are you sure it can be done?

Comment: @unknown__ last question: Is `B` initialized with zeros? if not, do you have the original values when reverting the distortion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `A` is the original cube, `B` is the distorted cube. That is,

```
B[i,j,k] = sum(A[i*,j*,k*] for i* <= i, j* <= j, k* <= k)
```

To get back `A` from `B`, do the following

```
A[i,j,k] = B[i, j, k]
         - B[i-1, j, k] - B[i, j-1, k] - B[i, j, k-1]
         + B[i, j-1, k-1] - B[i-1, j, k-1] - B[i-1, j-1, k]
         - B[i-1, j-1, k-1]
```

where `B[i,j,k] = 0` if `i < 0 or j < 0 or k < 0`

It follows from the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: thanks...btw .any good resource to read about this principle .??